# Python text file lines keep formatting

Tags: python, string, readlines

I am writing a short script to read in 1000 names from a text file, with each name on its own line. I need to make each name capital, then pad an asterisk onto the beginning and the end. Like * JOHN DOE *. What happens is that when it reads in the line it keeps the formatting, so it jumps to the next line each time before the last asterisk can be added. Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
def main():
    infile=open("putNamesHere.txt","r")
    outfile=open("getFromHere.txt","w")
    for line in infile:
        line=line.upper()
        mystring=('*'+line+'*')
        outfile.write(mystring)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove newline from the string:

```
def main():
    infile=open("putNamesHere.txt","r")
    outfile=open("getFromHere.txt","w")
    for line in infile:
        line=line.upper()
        mystring=('*'+line.rstrip()+'*\n')
        outfile.write(mystring)
```

Comment: Use `with ... as ...` or remember to `close` the files.

Comment: Consider using an argument to `str.rstrip()` if end-of-line white space needs to be preserved: `mystring='*'+line.rstrip('\n')+'*\n'`

Comment: The advice about `with ... as ...` should be done to the asker.